# How to expand a black region in a boolean image in matlab?

Tags: image, image-processing, matlab

I have a binary image in a matrix that I obtained by some image processing. When I say Binary Image I mean it has zeros and ones indicating complete black and complete white pixels. The image is mostly white and has some black spots. I now want to expand this black spots by some factor. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried dilate?

`imdilate(1-binary_image, SE)`

Where SE is the structural element.

Comment: I stumbled upon that but I do not have any SE. the shape of blacks are not consistent

Comment: @da_elysian_fields: The simplest structural element you can use is a matrix of ones: `ones(5,5)`. There is also a strel function that makes structural elements for you. For example `strel('disk',5)` will make a disk of radius 5.